# has_many polymorphism/inheritance in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, polymorphism, rails-postgresql

I am trying to set up a polymorphic relationship in Rails and have been running into some difficulty. Here's my data model:

```
class Order
    has_many :order_items
end

class OrderItem
    belongs_to :order
end

class PhysicalItem < OrderItem
end

class VirtualItem < OrderItem
end
```

PhysicalItem and VirtualItem have enough differences in their model to warrant being split out into their own tables. So, I envision there being:

an orders table

a physical_items table

a virtual_items table

an order_items table with item_type = ["PhysicalItem" or "VirtualItem"] and item_id of the matching row in the corresponding table.

I eventually want to be able to write code like this:

```
order = Order.new
physical_item = PhysicalItem.new
virtual_item = VirtualItem.new

order.order_items << physical_item
order.order_items << virtual_item

puts order.order_items
# Should list out the physical item and then the virtual item.
```

It seems very simple in theory, but it doesn't look like there's much support for this structure in general. Anyone have any thoughts about implementing this in a postgresql database with ActiveRecord?

Comment: When `PhysicalItem` and `VirtualItem` inherit from product, I do not see a product model in your list? Where does it fit into all of this?

Comment: I guess I don't really need the product model - the only thing that I get from it is the ability to query order.products and then retrieve a bunch of mixed PhysicalItems and VirtualItems.

Comment: Also, I edited my question to reflect my updated object names - sorry for the confusion before.

Comment: If you are using different tables consider using a gem that makes MTI easier.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need polymorphic associations for this. A method in the `Order` model would work just as well:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :physical_items
  has_many :virtual_items

  def order_items
    physical_items + virtual_items
  end
end

class PhysicalItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end

class VirtualItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

You will also need the `physical_items` and `virtual_items` tables to both have `order_id` columns. Then, to replicate the behavior you wanted:

```
order = Order.new
physical_item = order.physical_items.new
virtual_item = order.virtual_items.new

puts order.order_items
```

Comment: Sure, but let's say someone added 30 different items to their cart. I want to choose the first 10 items they added - I couldn't do that without querying all of the items, sorting the final list by the created_at timestamp, and then throwing away other models. This would be a very slow operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PostgreSQL HStore datatype in conjunction with STI. This way you gain the benefit of running a single `SELECT` on one table but that table is not polluted with type specific columns.

You will then have only two tables:

- orders table
- order_items table

For the order_items table the migration would consist of:

```
class CreateOrderItemsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :order_items do |t|
      t.integer :order_id
      t.string :type
      t.hstore :data
    end
  end
end
```

Your models would then look like this:

```
class Order
  has_many :order_items
end

class OrderItem
  belongs_to :order
  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end

class PhysicalItem < OrderItem
end

class VirtualItem < OrderItem
end
```

I tried using a polymorphic join table but it still required too many SQL quires just to get a list of the associations. HStore with STI is a great combination. For more information read this: http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2013-3-single-table-inheritance-hstore-lovely-combination